# Split tuple into two variables

Tags: javascript, split, tuples

```
latlng = (58.39847354300152, 15.579836368560791)
```

How do i split the above tuple so i get two variables like this

```
lat = 58.39847354300152
lng = 15.579836368560791
```

I have tried using split like this with no success

```
split = latlng.split(",");
lat = split[0];
lng = split[1];
```

Comment: Is that even valid ? Just try `latlng = (58.39847354300152, 15.579836368560791)` in the browsers' console

Comment: Javascript doesn't have a Tuple type, so what kind of value do you have? It is a string, an array or an object?

Comment: @karthikr it is valid syntax, but probably not what the OP expects.

Comment: @Tibos I am not talking about the syntax here.

Comment: @karthikr I think it's valid, but it's equivalent to `latlng = 15.579836368560791`

Comment: Looks like a python tuple. Is it mistagged possibly?

Comment: *"I have tried using split like this with no success"* What exactly didn't work with your approach? Did you get an **error** by any chance? This would tell us what `latlng` really is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am amusing it is a String

```
var latlng = "(58.39847354300152, 15.579836368560791)"

// Remove the parentheses and whitespace
latlng  = latlng.replace(/[() ]/g,'')

// Now your code 
var split = latlng.split(",");
var lat = split[0];
var lng = split[1];
```

Or as @wared says just match the digits and decimal point

```
var latlng = "(58.39847354300152, 15.579836368560791)"
var split = latlng.match(/\d+\.\d+/g)
```

Comment: +1 Wish you luck :D You could merge `replace` and `split` together using `match` : `split = latlng.match(/\d+\.\d+/g)`.

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming that OP was actually looking for [destructing assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). Although, this might not have been a language feature at the time.

```
const latLong = [58.39847354300152, 15.579836368560791];
const [lat, long] = latLong;
// is equivalent to:
// const lat = latLong[0];
// const long = latLong[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume latlng is an Array, since a tuple as you wrote it is not a valid way to store information.

```
var latlng = [58.39847354300152, 15.579836368560791];
var lat = latlng[0]; // 58.39847354300152
var lng = latlng[1]; // 15.579836368560791
```